# How to set onClickListener on RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

I have a simple problem that I can't set onClickListener on recyclerview , i don't want to set onClickListener on items of recyclerview , just the recyclerview itself , I tried the ordinary way and it didn't work

( i tried to set an onClickListener on the parent Layout but the strange things it doesn't work because of the LinearLayoutManager that i set on recyclerview :| )

here's my code :

```
mRecyclerView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("onClick","Clicked");
        }
    });
```

Adapter :

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private List<Message> mMessage;

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    private TextView txtSender;
    private TextView txtMessage;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        txtSender = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtSender);
        txtMessage = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtText);
    }

}
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View inflatedView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_item_row, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(inflatedView);
}


public RecyclerAdapter(List<Message> messages) {
    mMessage = messages;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Message msg = mMessage.get(position);
    holder.txtSender.setText(msg.getSender());
    holder.txtMessage.setText(msg.getmessage());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mMessage.size();
}
```

Comment: post your adapter code...

Comment: Have you tried embedding it in a FrameLayout and setting the listener on the FrameLayout?

Comment: Well, this code should work, but it seems like a strange thing to do because the row views will still consume the touch event.

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 here you are

Comment: @ifiok it doesn't work :(

Comment: @Milad on the XML layer, set the recyclerview clickable property to true and on the viewholder for the row items, set the clickable property to false.

Comment: @ifiok still doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

As per your need, you need to modify `R.layout.recyclerview_item_row`. Use a android `LinearLayout` put both of `TextView`(`R.id.txtSender` and `R.id.txtText`) inside that.

Modify your `ViewHolder` as below:

```
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
private LinearLayout lvContainer;
private TextView txtSender;
private TextView txtMessage;

public ViewHolder(View v) {
    super(v);
    lvContainer = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.lv_container); // R.id.lv_container this should be in your R.layout.recyclerview_item_row
    txtSender = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtSender);
    txtMessage = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtText);
}
}
```

Modify your `onBindViewHolder` as below

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
Message msg = mMessage.get(position);
holder.txtSender.setText(msg.getSender());
holder.txtMessage.setText(msg.getmessage());
holder.lvContainer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Handle your click here
    }
});
}
```

Comment: thanks but i don't need the item's onClickListener , there are spaces between items , i need to cover the whole screen

Comment: Whole screen means covering single row click or what?

Comment: sorry my English is not well so i didn't understand the single row click meaning very well , this is my problem :  i want an OnClickListener where ever on screen , i have 2 choices , first set OnClickListener for the RecyclerView or the parent layout ( root layout ) , i tried both and i failed , i don't know why , the only thing i know is setting layoutmanager stops the root layout onClickListener working

Comment: You must have seen `ListView` there are two click listener in that `setOnClickListener` which is called when listview is click another `setOnItemClickListener` which is called when listview item is click. Which behaviour you want for your `RecyclerView`? 

If you want second behaviour then my answer is your solution.

Comment: i want the first